# Kotlin Multiplatform app crashes on start

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

When I run my app, it is supposed to show a screen for a user to create an account or sign in. I had the code working as a regular kotlin app and decided to make a multiplatform app instead so I remade the project as multiplatform. KMM does not support this code:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sign_in.*`

so I had to change to ViewBinding. Here is the code I used previously and what I changed it to:

Before:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import com.cj.globekotlin.Extensions.toast
import com.cj.globekotlin.FirebaseUtils.firebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sign_in.*

class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var signInEmail: String
    lateinit var signInPassword: String
    lateinit var signInInputsArray: Array<EditText>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        signInInputsArray = arrayOf(etSignInEmail, etSignInPassword)
        btnCreateAccount2.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
            signInUser()
        }
    }

    private fun notEmpty(): Boolean = signInEmail.isNotEmpty() && signInPassword.isNotEmpty()

    private fun signInUser() {
        signInEmail = etSignInEmail.text.toString().trim()
        signInPassword = etSignInPassword.text.toString().trim()

        if (notEmpty()) {
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(signInEmail, signInPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener { signIn ->
                    if (signIn.isSuccessful) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                        toast("signed in successfully")
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        toast("sign in failed")
                    }
                }
        } else {
            signInInputsArray.forEach { input ->
                if (input.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    input.error = "${input.hint} is required"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import com.cj.globemultiplatform.android.Extensions.toast
import com.cj.globemultiplatform.android.FirebaseUtils.firebaseAuth
import com.cj.globemultiplatform.android.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding

class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var signInEmail: String
    lateinit var signInPassword: String
    lateinit var signInInputsArray: Array<EditText>

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        signInInputsArray = arrayOf(binding.etSignInEmail, binding.etSignInPassword)
        binding.btnCreateAccount2.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        binding.btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
            signInUser()
        }
    }

    private fun notEmpty(): Boolean = signInEmail.isNotEmpty() && signInPassword.isNotEmpty()

    private fun signInUser() {
        signInEmail = binding.etSignInEmail.text.toString().trim()
        signInPassword = binding.etSignInPassword.text.toString().trim()

        if (notEmpty()) {
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(signInEmail, signInPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener { signIn ->
                    if (signIn.isSuccessful) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
                        toast("signed in successfully")
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        toast("sign in failed")
                    }
                }
        } else {
            signInInputsArray.forEach { input ->
                if (input.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    input.error = "${input.hint} is required"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, I thought that this would work but now whenever I open the app, it crashes. I think this change is what's causing the crashes. Is that possible? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: What's the crash reason? You can find it inside Logcat by filtering `AndroidRuntime`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your android code:

1. There is no connection between your inflated binding and the content you are setting, you should use

```
binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

2. Your `lateinit var`iables for the inputs are used in the signInUser() method, but it's not initialised. I'd suggest removing that and using `binding.signInEmail` and the other views.

Also, if you're trying to share code between Android & iOS, you should be aware that you'll need to abstract away any platform specific implementation. For ex: all packages that are android specific will not work on iOS at this moment. This specific code is pretty Android platform heavy, thus I wouldn't even try to share this in a KMM app, only business logic, perhaps up to a ViewModel layer.